# How to initialize BertForSequenceClassification for different input rather than [CLS] token?

Tags: huggingface-transformers

BertForSequenceClassification uses [CLS] token's representation to feed a linear classifier. I want to leverage another token (say [X] in the input sequence) rather than [CLS]. What's the most straightforward way to implement that in Transformers?

Comment: Take the output from the last encoding layer and select the token you want.

Comment: You mean via editing 'BertForSequenceClassification' class? I'm wondering is there a better way? -Normally, it should be parameterised based on the representation token.

Comment: That is up to you. There are several ways to do it. In my opinion, it should not be parameterized because the library can't handle everything for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can define the special tokens when creating the tokenizer.

This is an example of how to modify an special token of a pretrained tokenizer:

```py
from transformers import BertTokenizer

tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased", cls_token="[X]")
```

Please check the [BertTokenizer documentation](https://huggingface.co/transformers/model_doc/bert.html#:%7E:text=configuration%20%3D%20model.config-,BertTokenizer,-class) to see which other special tokens you can modify (`unk_token`, `sep_token`, `pad_token`, `cls_token`, `mask_token`, etc.).